# Dummy variable in regression

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis

I have a dataset for countries. One variable is coded as 0,1,2 or 3. For one country, its values on this variable are 0,1 and 2 (i.e., there is no 3). I created three dummies for this variable (and not four), using one as the omitted category. I was wondering if this is correct? Similarly, for another country whose values on the variable are 0 and 1, is two dummies appropriate here?Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you combining the data sets in any way?

Comment: They are two separate regressions but I’m running the same model in each country. Thank you very much.